# ss exit code always 0

Tags: linux, networking

I'm trying put in a script a check to verify if there is a process listening on a port.

I'm tring to use `ss` but it seems to always produce 0 as a exit code , also if the expression is nor matched.

On this host I've a service listening on port 53 , it matches and has exit code 0

```
$ ss -ntl   sport = :53 ; echo $? 
State       Recv-Q Send-Q                                                            Local Address:Port                                                                           Peer Address:Port              
LISTEN      0      5                                                                     127.0.1.1:53                                                                                        *:*                  
LISTEN      0      5                                                                     127.0.0.1:53                                                                                        *:*                  
LISTEN      0      5                                                                           ::1:53                                                                                       :::*                  
0
```

If i change the port to 54 , where nothing is listening , the exit code remain always 0

```
$ss -ntl   sport = :54 ; echo $? 
State       Recv-Q Send-Q                                                            Local Address:Port                                                                           Peer Address:Port              
0
```

I've checked the manual , and there is nothing about the exit code.

Am I doing something wrong or is this behavior correct ?

tested both on ubuntu 16.04 and centos 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is normal, `ss` doesn’t change its exit code to indicate whether the filter matched anything.

If you want to test `ss`’s results, you need to post-process them with some other tool, *e.g.* `grep` (which does change its exit code depending on whether it matched):

```
ss -ntl sport = :53 | grep -q :53; echo $?
```

Comment: tried using ` lsof   -i :53` insted of  `ss`  and it give exit code 1 if nothing matches.  **PRO** more elegant solution (IMHO) **CONS** not always installed on all machines